# mockery::mock and mockery::stub do not work properly with quasiquotation?

Tags: r, unit-testing, mockery, testthat, quasiquotes

I've written an import function that gets a single file from an aws s3-bucket.

That function itself is a wrapper around `aws.s3::s3read_using()` which takes a reading function as its first argument.

Why do I wrap around `aws.s3::s3read_using()` ? Because I need to do some special error-handling and want the wrapping function to do some `Recall()` up to a limit... but that's a different story.

Now that i've successfully build and tested my wrapping function i want to do another wrapping arround that:

I want to iterate n times over my wrapper to bind the downloaded files together. I now have the difficulty to hand the 'reading_function' to the `FUN` argument of `aws.s3::s3read_using()`.

I could do that by simply using `...` - BUT!
I want to make clear to the USER of my wrapping wrapper, that he needs to specify that argument.

So I've decided to use rlangs `rlang::enexpr()` to capture the argument and to hand it over to my first wrapper via `!!` - which in return captures that argument again with `rlang::enexpr()` and hands it over - finally - to `aws.s3::s3read_using()` via `rlang::expr(aws.s3::s3read_using(FUN = !!reading_fn, object = s3_object))`

That works perfectly fine and smooth. My Problem is with testing that function construct using `testthat` and `mockery`

Here is some broadly simplyfied code:

```
my_workhorse_function <- function(fn_to_work_with, value_to_work_on) {
  fn <- rlang::enexpr(fn_to_work_with)
  # Some other magic happens here - error handling, condition-checking, etc...
  out <- eval(rlang::expr((!!fn)(value_to_work_on)))
}

my_iterating_function <- function(fn_to_iter_with, iterate_over) {
  fn <- rlang::enexpr(fn_to_iter_with)
  out <- list()
  for(i in seq_along(iterate_over)) {
    out[[i]] <- my_workhorse_function(!!fn, iterate_over[i])
  }
  return(out)
}

# Works just fine
my_iterating_function(sqrt, c(9:16))
```

Now, to the test:

```
# Throws an ERROR: 'Error in `!fn`: invalid argument type'
test_that("my_iterating_function iterates length(iterate_over) times over my_workhorse_function", {
  mock_1 <- mockery::mock(1, cycle = TRUE)
  stub(my_iterating_function, "my_workhorse_function", mock_1)
  expect_equal(my_iterating_function(sqrt, c(9:16)), list(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
  expect_called(mock_1, 8)
})
```

I've used a workarround, but that just doesn't feel right, even though, it works:

```
# Test passed
test_that("my_iterating_function iterates length(iterate_over) times over my_workhorse_function", {
  mock_1 <- mockery::mock(1, cycle = TRUE)
  stub(my_iterating_function, "my_workhorse_function", 
       function(fn_to_work_with, value_to_work_on) {
         fn <- rlang::enexpr(fn_to_work_with)
         out <- mock_1(fn, value_to_work_on)
         out})
  expect_equal(my_iterating_function(sqrt, c(9:16)), list(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
  expect_called(mock_1, 8)
})
```

I'm using version of `R: 4.1.1`
I'm using versions of `testthat(3.1.1)`, `mockery(0.4.2)`, `rlang(0.4.12)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're complicating things here, although maybe I'm not fully understanding your end goal. You can directly pass functions through arguments without any issue. Your example code above can be easily simplified to (keeping the loop just to match your `test_that()` call):

```r
library(testthat)
library(mockery)

my_workhorse_function <- function(fn_to_work_with, value_to_work_on) {
  fn_to_work_with(value_to_work_on)
}

my_iterating_function <- function(fn_to_iter_with, iterate_over) {
  out <- list()
  for(i in seq_along(iterate_over)) {
    out[[i]] <- my_workhorse_function(fn_to_iter_with, iterate_over[i])
  }
  return(out)
}

# Works just fine
my_iterating_function(sqrt, c(9:16))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> ...

test_that("my_iterating_function iterates length(iterate_over) times over my_workhorse_function", {
  mock_1 <- mockery::mock(1, cycle = TRUE)
  stub(my_iterating_function, "my_workhorse_function", mock_1)
  expect_equal(my_iterating_function(sqrt, c(9:16)), list(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
  expect_called(mock_1, 8)
})
#> Test passed
```

You can just pass `FUN` directly through all of your nested functions. The functions you're wrapping with `enexpr()` were never going to be evaluated in the first place until you explicitly call them. You usually use `enexpr` when users are supplying expressions, not just functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for that reminder of the basics :D  @caldwellst - I really tend to overcomplicate things - sometimes its just that simple. Now i might even replace the loop with a `purrr::map` function, because I wasn't able to get the `!!` running with that - lots to learn still!

Comment: No worries, and yes, just going with `map()` and dropping `my_iterating_function()` would be a lot cleaner. You can accept the answer if this has solved your problem, thanks!